# Looking for a Mathematical Derivation for the Energy Formula in Continuous-time Domain

Tags: continuous-signals, signal-energy, derivation

I have just started my signal and system course and I would like to know how we derive the corresponding formula for the energy of a continuous-time signal $x(t)$ over an interval $[t_{1},t_{2}]$ :

> $$E_{x}=\displaystyle\int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}|x(t)|^{2}\;\text{d}t$$

That is to say why is the signal energy the area under the region of the square of $x(t)$. For instance, I can think of $x(t):=t$ with $t$ being geometrically the first bisector and so by squaring it we obtain a parabola so this would mean the energy is the area under this parabola but why is this true?

Comment: A good explanation is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I will take a look at this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the energy of a signal over an interval isn't a *derivation*.  It's a *definition*.  You do that integration and you *call the result* the signal's energy.

The reason that in the mathematical world we make that definition is because (A) it makes the math handy, and (B) for a preponderance (but by no means all) of the means of signal transmission in the real world, the actual, physical, energy of a signal over an interval really is proportional to its amplitude squared.

So if you launch a radio signal into free space with an antenna, you couple into free space where the actual physical energy of the signal is proportional to its amplitude squared.  When you launch a sonar signal into the water with a transducer, the actual physical energy of the signal is proportional to its amplitude squared.  When you launch an electronic signal into a transmission line, the actual energy of the forward-traveling portion of the resulting wave is proportional to the amplitude squared.  Etc.

So -- just accept it because it makes the math handy, and be happy that the real world happens to fit with an expression that also makes the math handy.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I will therefore accept it the way it is $:)$

Answer (score 0):

All of these squared energy terms come from the basic physics of simple harmonic motion (SHM), where there is a restoring force proportional to displacement.  This can be mechanical, electric field, magnetic field, etc etc.  When f(x) = -kx, energy = 0.5 k x^2 + c, since force is by definition the derivative of energy.